# SQL Result set with Max function and adjacent row results

Tags: sql-server-2008, max, resultset

I have four columns output in my resultset:

Name, Subject, Grade, Value

Is it possible to populate a result set using the Max(Value), but also bring through it's adjacent Subject and Grade and how would I achieve this? eg:

```
Name    Subject    Grade    Value
Helen   Chemistry  C        7
Helen   Physics    B        8
Helen   Biology    A        9
Brad    Chemistry  C        7
Brad    Biology    D        6
Brad    Physics    F        4
```

Becomes

```
Name    Subject    Grade    Value
Helen   Biology    A        9
Brad    Chemistry  C        7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY value DESC) rn
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: Important to note in this context, I believe, that if there is a tie for the top `value` for any individual, this query will return one of those rows, arbitrarily. To control which row is chosen, more criteria could be applied in the `ORDER BY`. If ties are wanted in the result, a switch to `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` would be indicated.